A Russian Olympiad Problem On A Game Of Cards
The following problem is from the Leningrad Math Olympiad, 1988:

There are 25 people sitting around a table, and each
person has two cards. One of the numbers 1 , 2, 3 , ... , 25 is written on each card, and
each number occurs on exactly two cards. At a signal, each person passes one of
her cards-the one with the smaller number-to her right-hand neighbor. Prove that,
sooner or later, one of the players will have two cards with the same numbers.

This problem has been referenced a couple of times on stack exchange (for eg. here, here and here), but I have a different solution to offer. However, this isn't merely a solution verification post, but a question regarding a small problem with my proof, which I don't know how to resolve.
My proof is as follows:
Proof:
Denote the cards of a player as $(a,b)$ where $a$ is the smaller numbered card (and, thus, $b$ is the larger numbered card). Consider the following 3-player system:
$$(1,3)$$
$$(2,3)$$
$$(1,2)$$
The first bracketed term represents the cards of a particular player on the table. The one below represents the cards of the player on his right. The next line is the player's cards on his right etc. So, after one pass, you can imagine the first number just shifting one line down while keeping the second number fixed. This is because the smaller number is to be switched. Hence, after a pass:
$$(1,3)$$
$$(1,3)$$
$$(2,2)$$
So the first column of numbers has basically shifted down by a line, with the last number of the first column going back up top (so you can just think of the first column of numbers as a series of beads stacked vertically on each other. Then, swapping cards is like removing the bottommost bead, causing all the others to fall down by one "bead diameter", and placing that bottommost bead on top). Notice that through this entire process, the second column stays fixed.
Now, the $(2,2)$ was formed because both columns had a common number in the first place (that is, the number two) and rearranging the first column eventually caused the common number to line up.
All that is to be shown is that with 25 players, both columns will always have a common number. Then, we're done. This is in fact true for any odd $n$ (not just $n = 25$). Suppose $n = 7$ and that you can generate two columns with no common number. Given that you can repeat a number at most twice, you need to place a minimum of four distinct numbers in the 7 spots of the first column:
$$1122334$$
Now, the same applies to the second column. You'd need to put four distinct numbers in the second column. So, you'd need 8 distinct numbers for both columns to have no common number, which is a contradiction since you can choose only from 1 to 7.
This problem does not arise for even $n$, and, thus, you can find a configuration for an even number of players such that, no matter how many passes are done, no player gets common numbered cards.
But, in this argument, a problem arises. Specifically, consider the following configuration:
$$(1,2)$$
$$(2,5)$$
$$(1,3)$$
$$(3,4)$$
$$(4,5)$$
After the first pass, I get:
$$(4,2)$$
$$(1,5)$$
$$(2,3)$$
$$(1,4)$$
$$(3,5)$$
The problem is that the first player doesn't have his cards in ascending order. Switching the cards will break the fact that the second column remained fixed, which was an essential part of my argument. So how do I resolve this problem?

Should there be three 2's and one 3?

Ah yes. I've modified the configuration

You have argued that if the second column stays fixed, then we are done. I agree that the second column is not necessarily fixed right from the start. $\quad$ So, to fill in the gap of your solution, show that eventually the second column stays constant, then apply the rest of your solution. As it turns out, this works. This idea is also expressed in Egor's solution. $\quad$ For the cherry on top, while it is not required for the solution, can you determine what the eventually fixed second column will be?

Th maximum card value each person has is monotonically increasing (with respect to the number of turns player) and bounded above and is hence convergent. Because it is an integer series you can then say that eventually, the second column will stay constant.

@CalvinLin Is this line of reasoning sufficient: define a problematic number to be a number in column 1 such that there exists at least one number in column 2 that is smaller. There is an upper bound on the number of problematic numbers: 25. If a problematic number lines up with a number lower than it in column 2, swap the two numbers. Eventually, the number of problematic numbers would go to zero

As written, that argument is not sufficient. Why must a bounded sequence of integers go to 0? EG 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, ... You need to show something more. EG You claim that the sequence must eventually decrease on one indicator variable, but does the TOTAL number of problematic numbers actually decrease? (Yes, but not shown) Could it stay constant in that step, or even increase? (as it turns out, no)  $\quad$ We could fix this gap by showing 1/ monotonicity (which still isn't sufficient), and 2/ If non-zero, we can force a strict decrease within 25 turns. Hence, this sequence is eventually 0.

A way to phrase it more simply is to color all the $1$ to $12$ cards and one of the $13$ cards blue and the other cards red. If player who is holding a blue card is passed a red card, they will swap to holding a red card, but not vice versa, so the number of red cards being held can only increase. And if any red cards are being passed, some player must be holding a blue card, and the red card will eventually reach them. So the number of held red cards cannot stay the same indefinitely. Eventually it must be that all held cards are red, at which case the two 13 cards will eventually meet.
